# Cross Domain Javascript/AJAX issue

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, ajax

I have an issue with a dropdown selection that is calling an API.  It will allow the user to select from the database when the URL has www like so http://www.staynsurf.com/modules/listing/address_description.php?.... but the error comes up if the URL does not have www. (i.e. http://staynsurf.com/modules/listing/address_description.php?....).

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function getXMLHTTP() {
    var xmlhttp=false;  
    try{
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch(e)    {       
        try{            
            xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e){
            try{
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e1){
                xmlhttp=false;
            }
        }
    }

    return xmlhttp;
}

function getState(countryId) {      

    var strURL="http://www.staynsurf.com/findState.php?country="+countryId;
    var req = getXMLHTTP();

    if (req) {

        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                // only if "OK"
                if (req.status == 200) {                        
                    document.getElementById('statediv').innerHTML=req.responseText;                     
                } else {
                    alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                }
            }               
        }           
        req.open("GET", strURL, true);
        req.send(null);
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use AJAX, the domain of the calling page and target URL must be the same. `www.stansurf.com` and `staynsurf.com` are not the same (the browser has no way to know that you've made them equivalent on the server).

The easiest solution is to leave the domain out of the target URL, so it will use the same domain as the calling page automatically:

```
var strURL="/findState.php?country="+countryId;
```